# Xcode 15 Release candidate Simulator issue

Tags: ios, ios17, xcode15

Facing an error while downloading iOS17 Simulator

Registering simulator runtime with CoreSimulator failed. Having enough space in my machine.

[image]

15th september. Mac OS ventura 13.5.2

Any inputs will be really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: try resetting CoreSimulator service using 'xcrun simctl erase all' then download simulator again

Comment: Tried that but No luck Arpan.

Comment: It requires more space. Even around 20GB was not enough. with more space it worked finally.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:**

You can try downloading and installing iOS 17.0 Simulator runtimes for a specific platform using the `Terminal`. Use the `-downloadPlatform` option and specify the platform like this:

```
xcodebuild -downloadPlatform iOS
```

**Option 2:**

You can download the iOS 17.0 simulator runtime from this link - https://developer.apple.com/download/all/
After downloading the runtime, follow the commands below in your Terminal:

```
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app
xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch
xcrun simctl runtime add "~/Downloads/iOS_17_Simulator_Runtime.dmg"
```